# ContentControl with DataTemplateSelector and bound Content

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-runtime, contentcontrol

I have the following `ContentControl` two-way binded with a `Current` property that shows the current selection of my `ListView`.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Current}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelector}">
```

It uses a `DataTemplateSelector` that returns 1 of 2 `DataTemplates`, one when the `Content` is `null` and the other one when it is not.

When I start my app the `Current` property is `null` and the correct `DataTemplate`is applied.

When I select one `ListViewItem`, `Current`property is not `null` and the `ContentControl DataTemplate` changes as it should.

When I unselect the `ListViewItem`, `Current`property is `null` again and the `ContentControl` disappears and none of the `DataTemplates` are applied.

I made breakpoints and output some data to the console and I discover that **DataTemplateSelector does not runs when `Current` changes to null. However it runs the first time when it is also null.** So I don't understand why is this happening. Anyone had this issue or a similar one?

Comment: How are you deselecting?

Comment: To deselect I click on the selected item. `Current` property is two-way binded with SelectedItem of ListView.

Answer (score 2):

When you deselect the item, selected item of the list box becomes null, thus the binding to `Current` cannot find the property.

In this case, trying to access `Current` doesn't return `null` it returns null reference exception which is swallowed by binding.

I'm assuming that you bind to the selected item (whether directly off the list box or routed through view model) in some way. Something like:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <ContentControl ..../>
</Grid>
```

If so, you'd need to change bindings and the logic of template selector:

At ContentControl:

```
Content="{Binding }"
```

In related data templates, you'd need to add `Current.` at the beginning of all paths in all bindings.

In data template selector instead of checking the value, check the `Current` property (and if the casting of value fails, consider it null).

Comment: first of all thank you for your help. `SelectedItem` is not the `DataContext`. The `DataContext` is a ViewModel that owns the `Current` property that it is binded with `ListView.SelectedItem` property.

Comment: However I think this can be a workaround and you have my vote but since my `ContentControl` shares its `DataTemplate` with my `ListView` I will need to change also the data binding logic to my `ListView`. I went temporarily with a shorter workaround. I binded `ContentControl` with an auxiliar property `ContentControl_Current` that has only one difference from `Current`. When `Current` is `null` I assign a meaningless `string` to it and now `DataTemplateSelector` checks for **string type instead of null value**.

Comment: But as I said temporarily. I just need my `DataTemplateSelector` to catch that **null reference exception** that you mentioned. If so I won't have this problem anymore. Do you think it is possible or it will always be swallowed?

Comment: I think `Binding` will always swallow it. I'd need more time to think about it. Will update here if I find something.